# Zoom QGraphicsItem to fit QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to create a `QGraphicsView` that will allow someone to scale the current `QGraphicsItem` to fit the size of the `QGraphicsView` window.

I have overridden `QGraphicsItem` to create a custom version, and I implemented some methods so it knows how much it has been scaled (which is always proportional to the original, so there is only one scale factor - the same for width and height).

So in the `scaleFactor` setter I have the following:

```
void ImagePixmapItem::setScaleFactor(float sf){
    scaleFactor = sf;
    this->boundingRect().setWidth(this->boundingRect().width()*scaleFactor);
    this->boundingRect().setHeight(this->boundingRect().height()*scaleFactor);

}
```

And in my main form, I have the following in a button:

```
   QRect portRect = ui->graphicsView->viewport()->rect();
    double scaleFactorX;
   if(portRect.width() <= (item->boundingRect().size().width()))
       scaleFactorX =portRect.width() /(item->boundingRect().size().width());
   else
       scaleFactorX = (item->boundingRect().size().width())/portRect.width();

    qDebug("Scalefactor: %4.3f \n", scaleFactorX);
    qDebug("item width: %4.3f \n", item->boundingRect().size().width());
    qDebug("item height: %4.3f \n", item->boundingRect().size().height());
    item->setScaleFactor(scaleFactorX);
    item->scale(scaleFactorX,scaleFactorX);
```

Where `item` is one of those `ImagePixmapItem`s.

This works good the first time time - my image is larger than the viewport, and it scales down nicely to fit the window (at least width wise). However, if I hit the button again, the same value for `scaleFactorX` and `item` width and height come back.

Can you change the `boundingRect` of an image after it has been transformed? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [`QGraphicsItem::boundingRect()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) returns a copy of the rect. Changing it has no effect on the actual item. To change an item's geometry, you need to override that function and return a different rect. And call [`prepareGeometryChange()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#prepareGeometryChange) when you actually change it.

Now, if all you want is to fit the item in QGraphicsView's viewport, use [`QGraphicsView::fitInView()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView-3).

Changing the transformation of an item is very different from changing the transformation from the scene to the view. The former changes how the item is placed in the scene in relation to other items. The later keeps the relation and only affect how the scene is "reflected" onto the view.

It doesn't make much difference if you have a single item in the scene. Just keep in mind when you are dealing more complex scene that item transformation deals with the mathematical model of your world, not how to view it.

**Edit:**

I just reread your code. It turns out you are calculating the scale factor wrong. Here's a basic, non-tested code:

```
QRect itemSize = graphicsView->mapFromScene(item->sceneBoundingRect()).boundingRect().size();
QRect scaledSize =itemSize.scale(graphicsView->viewport().size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
double ratio = qMin((double)scaledSize.width()/itemSize().width(), (double)scaledSize.height()/itemSize().height());
item->setTransform(QTransform::fromScale(ratio,ratio), true);
```

The point is to use `sceneBoundingRect` instead of `boundingRect` since `boundingRect` is the item local bounds which is always the same regardless of item transform. And sceneBoundingRect is the bounds after all `transformations` are applied.

Comment: if I use fitInView, does this actually scale the ITEM itself? Keep in mind, If i have several items in the scene, I actually want to manipulate the single item that has focus to fit in the view, not just zoom so that that the view itself gets scaled to fit the item in the view

Comment: I didn't realize you do want to manipulate individual item size. Then `fitToView` is not the answer. Sorry. However, your `setScaleFactor()` has no effect at all since it's just setting a temp. See my edit for scaling individual item.